# display custom post on separate page

Tags: custom-post-types, functions

I have been able to register a new post type. 'code' and now I would like to display it. I added

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_get_posts' );

function my_get_posts( $query ) {
if ( is_home() )
    $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'page', 'album', 'movie', 'quote', 'code', 'attachment' ) );
    return $query;
}
```

but this makes it show with other blog posts. I want a new page that only displays 'code' posts. I created a file single-code.php but I dont think this is correct. How do I create a new page that just shows code posts?

Comment: If all you want is a page that shows a list (or excerpts) of that post type, then it's already enabled through your rewrites: `myblog.com/?post_type=code`. Then you can customize the look with `archive-code.php`. See http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy

Comment: Thats not exactly what I want. I would like myblog.com/code to be the url and then on that page i see all those code posts and only the code posts. How do I make that page?

Comment: Josh, I think Tom has given a solid answer on this one IMO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to create Page (maybe call it "All Codes"). Then, you "hijack" that page's PHP template by creating a PHP file in your theme's directory called `page-all-codes.php` (note how the "all-codes" part corresponds to the slug of the Page you created).

You can then use [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) to get a list of your posts. Your arguments should look like this - feel free to add more to customize your list (like how you want them ordered etc)

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'code',
  'posts_per_page' => -1
);
```

How you use these $args is up to you. The easiest (and in this case, probably not so bad) way is `query_posts( $args );`.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just create the template archive-code.php, and that will loop through your 'code' only custom post types.

And then if you created a single-code.php template page, that will be how your custom post types 'code' will be displayed if it is a single page.